# Redirect only WordPress homepage with a 301 redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a blog, lets say `example.com` and another blog installed in `example.com/np` which is not multisite but a different WordPress installation.

What I want is to redirect `example.com` homepage only to `example.com/np`. It would be great if that redirection is a 301 moved permanently redirection.

If I place the 301 redirection in WordPress header file, `header.php`, it will redirect every page. And if I check if the page is home and try a 301 redirection that's not possible because header redirection should be placed at top.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you're in the context of WordPress, you can utilize its redirect functionality.

**Like this ( in functions.php ):**

```
function redirect_homepage() {
    if( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    wp_redirect( 'http://redirect-here.com', 301 );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_homepage' );
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to muddle in your Wordpress templates or code for this, just use a single mod_rewrite rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule / /np [R=301,L]
```

Put it below the `RewriteEngine on` line if it's already there, else add it as a separate line above the `RewriteRule` line.

This solution is easily removable, easily maintainable, portable, and performs better than doing it in PHP in the templates or WP code, and survives updates to your templates.

Comment: This is probably the best answer - if you plan on keeping your theme up to date, you won't have to worry about overwriting code. +1

Comment: I'd rather see `wp_redirect` used and keep the redirect code in a child theme. Updating your theme code won't be an issue if you use a child theme, which is the recommended way of altering theme behavior: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

`.htaccess` could also be overwritten simply by an update to the permalink structure.

Comment: Means there was a `RewriteBase /` in there - I couldn't know ;)

Comment: I set this rule and first it doesn't work and second it breaks my website. I have an MU installation

Answer (score 4):

Put the following in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'so16738311_redirect', 0 );
function so16738311_redirect()
{
    if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/np/' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually more contextually appropriate to hook on `template_redirect`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function of WordPress with status code. add Follwing code on wordpress init hook

```
if ( is_home() ) {
    wp_redirect( $location, $status );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.Your domain/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Wordpress function to detect if you're on the home page:

**is_home**

> > http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage - 301 Redirect
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/np");
    exit;
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

Comment: This is possible for normal redirection but as far as I know 301 redirection is not possible within this code. Please correct me if I am incorrect.

Comment: WordPress provides a function for this `wp_redirect`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)  or [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) function to redirect your home page.

Comment: You haven't answered his question, though. He wants to know how to redirect from his homepage, not just determine if the homepage is requested. :)

Answer (score -3):

Just put this at the very top of your `index.php` file of your wordpress installation:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/"){
    include('......server file directory to file you want to redirect to');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Never change WordPress core codes. It might break after version upgrade.