# Intermingling HTML/CSS/JS landing page with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have created a landing page using HTML/CSS/JS which will be at `www.example.com/welcome`

The home site is built in WordPress, `www.example.com`. I want only the home page of `www.example.com` to redirect to this landing page `www.example.com/welcome`, not the entire site, so no 301 redirect. In my research I have found that adding this code to your htaccess will redirect your home page only, is that correct?

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.example.com/welcome
```

Comment: That's a simple enough question to answer by testing. Drop it in the .htaccess file, load, and see if it worked. You can also test with wheregoes.com and they will tell you whether it was a 301 or 302 redirect.

Comment: Solution on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16739385/1287812)